# C# async cancel with exception

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, .net-core, cancellation-token

so - Ive written a server that will listen on a port - and you can just await it to basically hang around indefinitely. It also takes a cancellation token that kills it. Both the server and cancellation token work.

*So - I have some unit tests that look like this:*

```cs
    var cancel = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var server = CreateServer( cancel.Token );
    var check = await CallServer();
    Assert.Equal( something, check );
    tokenSource.Cancel();
    await server;
```

*ie - the idea is to start a server, call it - then tell it to shut down gracefully, and finally wait around until it's done so.*

ALL OF THAT WORKS.

when everything is good... however... IF I break something in the server - such that it throws an exception - the exception just vanishes - never appears anywhere - and the "await server" command hangs forever (or at least until the CI times out and kills the process)

if I put the `await server = createserver` on one line - the exception properly comes out.  Now, obviously there's something wrong with awaiting something that's had an exception and just been cancelled, but I can't figure it out.

So - how do I fix this?  What *should* I be doing, either to properly catch the exception or to cancel the server in a better way, or to restructure this code better?

Comment: _"the exception just vanishes - never appears anywhere - and the "await server" command hangs forever"_ - Unless I've misunderstood, it sounds like you have a deadlock. Presumably further up the chain you're simply calling `.Wait()` rather than working with `await TASK` all the way up the chain. `await` unwraps exceptions for you, so they won't just go poof.

Comment: How does the call site looks like? Does it have `async void` in its declaration?

Comment: What is the type of the `server` variable?

Comment: the server is my code - it is basically just    var run = host.RunAsync(_cancellation); if (somethingFalse) {};    await run;   where host is a Kestrel web server built with webhostbuilder.      _I_ am certainly never call wait, but I have no idea what runasync does.  the createServer function is just async Task CreateServer().

Comment: the real problem here is of course - it works perfectly on my box, but hangs forever on the ci machine - so I can't debug it :(

Comment: Just out of curiousity: 
Have you already tried `await CallServer.ConfigureAwait(false); `

Comment: I wonder if the user that is running the CI builds has the correct rights to start the kestrel web server. Maybe you should try mocking that behavior, i.e. create a wrapper around your webserver, and pass a mock of it from the test. To verify, you could try to change the user that runs the build agent to something that has more access... although, it shouldn't have anything to do with the awaiting. hm.

Comment: What is the type of the application? Windows Service? Console? WinForms?

Comment: it's a console app

Comment: Can you post the code of the `CreateServer` method?